# Octal digit in ANSI C grammar (lex)

Tags: c, regex, grammar, lex

I looked [ANSI C grammar (lex)](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html#MOD-ASSIGN).

And this is octal digit regex

```
0{D}+{IS}?      { count(); return(CONSTANT); }
```

My question is why do they accept something like `0898`?

It's not an octal digit.

So i thought they would consider that, but they just have wrote like that.

Could you explain why is that? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want reasonable, user-friendly error messages.

If your lexer accepts `0999`, you can detect an illegal octal digit and output a reasonable message:

> ```
>  int x = 0999;
>           ^
>  error: illegal octal digit, go back to school
> ```

If it doesn't, it will parse this as two separate tokens `0` and `999` and pass them to the parser. The resulting error messages could be quite confusing.

> ```
>  int x = 0999;
>           ^
>  error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
> ```

The invalid program is rejected either way, as it should, however the ostensibly incorrect lex grammar does a better job with error reporting.

This demonstrates that practical grammars built for tools such as `lex` or `yacc` do not have to correspond exactly to ideal grammars found in language definitions.

Comment: This answer would be reasonable for other languages, but in C the initial tokenisation is done with the preprocessor token rules. Tokens which survive preprocessing must then be converted to syntactic tokens or an error message produced if that is not possible. So there is no possibility of accidentally dividing `0999` into two tokens. It is a single preprocessing token and remains a single token for the duration of the parse.

Comment: @rici An implementation doesn't have to physically use preprocessing tokens or any other concept defined by the standard. It is enough that the results are as described by the standard. A valid C program cannot contain 0999. A program that contains 0999 must be rejected. An implementation is perfectly capable of this even if it doesn't have any data stucture that correaponds to the peeprocessing token concept.

Comment: A valid program can certainly contain `0999` if, for example, it is only used with the stringify operator.

Comment: @rici I mean after preprocessing.

Comment: Sure, but when examining the actual text of the program, you have to use the actual rules of the language (or equivalent, as you say), and that implies not rejecting `0999` when you see it in the program text.

Comment: @rici We are not talking about examining the actual text of the program. Most C parsers and lexers historically didn't do that. They delegated the job to the preprocessor, and worked on preprocessed programs. The C standard mostly talks about the grammar of the language that describes preprocessed C programs.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar you repeatedly link to in your questions was produced in **1985**, **4 years prior to** the publication of the first C standard revision in 1989.

That is **not** the grammar that was published in the standard of [1989](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#octal-constant), which clearly uses

> *octal-constant*:
>
> - `0`
> - *octal-constant octal-digit*
>
> *octal-digit:* **one of**
>
> - `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7`

Even then, that Lex grammar is sufficient for tokenizing a *valid* program.

Comment: OP is showing buildable `lex` code. What was published in 1989 is not `lex` code but a computer-science-y grammar in BNF-ish notation.

Comment: @n.m. so? The point is here that OP has been asking questions as if that would be **the** grammar definition of the C programming language. Clearly it is not. Your answer is showing the other side of it. I did consider that too. Alas I ran out of votes already

Comment: You cannot correctly lex a C program without taking the preprocessor rules into account. A correct program could include the preprocessing token `0999` provided that it is never used as a token. It could, for example, be stringified without violating any constraint.

Comment: Now *that* is true

Comment: @rici OTOH that lex file does not handle preprocessor at all

Comment: Yes, so it is not lexing C.

Comment: @rici It is lexing a slightly different language which we can call "preprocessed C". The C standard specifies the grammar of preprocessed C, rather than C, in the bulk of its text (except for the part that talks about the preprocessor).

Comment: @n.m.: the grammar, yes. But we're talking here about the lexical structure, which is divided into tokens according to the preprocessor lexicon. Afterwards, each individual token is classified as a syntactic element, which includes distinguishing type names from other identifiers and thus is not strictly context-free.

Comment: @rici The standard describes an abstract machine. An implementation can do none of these things physically, and still be conforming, per the as-if rule.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that this is only syntax, not semantic.
So it is sufficient to detect "Cannot be anything but a constant.".
It is not necessary (yet) to detect "A correct octal constant.".

Note that it does not even make a difference between octal, decimal, hexadecimal. All of them register as "CONSTANT".